# Importing WMF (Windows Metafile) or any other vector file into a silverlight project

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, pixelsense

Is it possible to import WMF (Windows Metafile) or any other vector based file into a silverlight project?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at free [Silverlight Contrib project](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Feature%20Overview&ANCHOR) at codeplex. It comes with control to display WMF and EMF files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Paste2Xaml to convert WMF/EMF to XAML

http://www.wpf-graphics.com/Paste2Xaml.aspx

And (from the same source) ViewerSvg to convert SVG to XAML

http://www.wpf-graphics.com/ViewerSvg.aspx

Also, for SVG, InkScape has a XAML export feature and there's a XAML export plugin for Adobe Illustrator somewhere, for WMF, Microsoft Expression Graphics Designer (what a short name) is supposed to be able to import WMF and export XAML, but I haven't used those myself.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape can import wmf and export xaml: http://www.inkscape.org.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct way, but I've definitely transformed SVG into XAML successfully before. **[See this brief guide.](http://www.uxpassion.com/2008/10/how-to-convert-svg-to-xaml-and-use-it-in-silverlight-or-wpf/)**